# undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby

I'm writing a quick script to extract data from a device with a CLI via telnet. I could use a little help with an error that I'm not sure how to handle.

```
res = nil
res = t.cmd('actual command').match(/Calls:\s(\d{1,})/)[1].to_i
```

In some cases, the device is printing out all kinds of autonomous output at a rapid rate. Also, during this time, the device sometimes doesn't return all of the output which results in  no match. Thus, I get the following error:

```
in `<main>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

I've tried a few different things and can't seem to get past this issue. Thank you for any help with this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you see `undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass` it means:

> Hey! You have a value that is `nil` followed by `[...]`, but `nil` doesn't have this method.

In this case, your problem is that `match(...)` is sometimes failing to match the text you want, returning `nil`, and then you can't ask for `[1]` of that. Some direct approaches to avoid this are:

```
match = t.cmd('actual command').match(/Calls:\s(\d{1,})/)
res = match && match[1].to_i

# or
res = match[1].to_i if match

# or 
res = if (match=t.cmd('actual command').match(/Calls:\s(\d{1,})/))
  match[1].to_i
end

# or
res = (match=t.cmd('actual command').match(/Calls:\s(\d{1,})/)) && match[1].to_i
```

However, a simpler solution is to use the [`String#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) method to pull out the regex capture directly:

```
res = t.cmd('actual command')[/Calls:\s(\d+)/,1]
res = res.to_i if res
```

This form automatically returns `nil` for you if the regex fails, and you don't want to call `to_i` on `nil`.

<sub>*I also cleaned up your regex a little, since `\d{1,}` is equivalent to `\d+`.*</sub>

Comment: I didn't know that String#[] could do that automatically, that's a nice improvement!

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth explanation. It is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You need conditions to check if matching result is nil. Try something like this:

```
res = nil
res = t.cmd('actual command').match(/Calls:\s(\d{1,})/)[1].to_i rescue nil
```

The res variable will stay nil, so you can do some checks with this information later.

Comment: Note that using `rescue nil` is often frowned upon, because (a) it can hide any number of other problems, and (b) using exception handling is quite slow compared to checking for and avoiding exceptions yourself. Further, there is no need to set `res` to `nil` before this line.

Comment: I'm not frowning because sometimes it is desirable to hide the problems like this. The ```rescue nil``` at the end allows the match regex line to succeed with no error "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)".  ie. its a successful one liner which returns nil or the desired result.